# Modify data field name in R lm$call

Tags: r, purrr, lm

I have to fit several linear models that will be feed to other functions. Since they all have the same structure, I wanted to use `map` from `purrr` to get things done faster. Something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- data_frame(programme = rep(rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), each = 10),10), value = rnorm(300),
                   phase = rep(c("incoming", "torque"),150))
splitted_data <- data %>%
  split(., .$phase) 
all_lms <-  splitted_data %>%
   map(~lm(value~programme, .))
```

So here I am comparing the three programs separately for the two phases (I have much more models than this).
This is fast, however, looking at the call stored in the lm objects, one can see that the `data` field is equal to `.`

```
all_lms$incoming$call$data
```

If I want to use this list further down the line with other functions that need to know where the data used to fit the model are stored, I would need to change this field to the actual name of the object where the data are stored, so for example for `all_lms$incoming$call$data` I would like to have `splitted_data$incoming`.

If I try to assign another value to the data field as a string, as in
`all_lms$incoming$call$data <- "splitted_data$incoming"`, it doesn't work, as it is, well a string, and not the object. At the same time, if I try to assign it as an object, as in `all_lms$incoming$call$data <- splitted_data$incoming`, it is **all** the actual object that is assigned, i.e. the data frame, and not a link to the object.

Is there a way to do what I want or should I just perform the pipeline model by model several times ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your method already does assign just a reference to the object (or a "link" to the object as you put it), rather than copying it. For his book [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/) Hadley Wickham created the tool lobstr to help track references

```
> library(lobstr)
> library(tidyverse)
> data <- data_frame(programme = rep(rep(c('A', 'B', 'C'), each = 10),10), value = rnorm(300),
                   phase = rep(c("incoming", "torque"),150))
> splitted_data <- data %>%
  split(., .$phase) 
> all_lms <-  splitted_data %>%
   map(~lm(value~programme, .))
> all_lms$incoming$call$data <- splitted_data$incoming
> lobstr::obj_addr(all_lms$incoming$call$data)
[1] "0x158be36a8"
> lobstr::obj_addr(splitted_data$incoming)
[1] "0x158be36a8"
```

They both point to the same object. `all_lms$incoming$call$data` doesn't get copied to it's own object unless it's modified

```
> all_lms$incoming$call$data[1, "value"] <- 2
> lobstr::obj_addr(all_lms$incoming$call$data)
[1] "0x1594845c8"
```

Read all about this **copy-on-modify** at https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#copy-on-modify